# single-row subquery returns more than one row - No update or insert

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have written the following script

```
SELECT vil.account_id , 
       vil.imp_id, 
       vil.owner ,
       vil.start_date,
       CASE  
         WHEN ac.status = 4  
         THEN status_date  
         ELSE NULL  
       END AS Live_date,
       cs.country_code  
  FROM ACCOUNT ac  
  INNER JOIN vu_imp_list vil  
     ON vil.account_id = ac.account_id  
  INNER JOIN entity e  
     ON ac.entity_id = e.entity_id  
  INNER JOIN country_specifics cs  
     ON e.country_id = cs.country_id  
  WHERE (vil.account_id, vil.start_date) =   
        (SELECT vils.account_id, MIN(vils.start_date)   
           FROM vu_imp_list vils  
          WHERE vil.account_id IN  ('825808009','987323136')  
          group by vils.account_id);
```

But I keep receiving the error

```
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row  
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

I tried to add `rownum = 1` to the `where` clause for the sub-query, but seems the query is running forever. I've tested the sub-query separately and it returns one row for each `account_id`. Most of similar problems here are related to `insert` and `update` issues rather than just a query.

Comment: The subquery will return two rows, one for account_id 825808009 and another for account_id 987323136, so the error message looks clear enough.  Did you intend to use IN instead of = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the subquery returns exactly 1 row (or 0). I think you want this:

```
  WHERE vil.start_date =   
        (SELECT MIN(vils.start_date)   
           FROM vu_imp_list vils  
          WHERE vils.account_id IN ('825808009','987323136')  
        );
```

or use `IN` if the subquery returns 2 or more rows and you want to compare `start_date` with any of them:

```
  WHERE vil.start_date IN   
        (SELECT MIN(vils.start_date)   
           FROM vu_imp_list vils  
          WHERE vils.account_id IN ('825808009','987323136')
          GROUP BY vils.account_id 
        );
```

or perhaps this, if you want a correlated subquery:

```
  WHERE vil.account_id IN ('825808009','987323136')
    AND vil.start_date =   
        (SELECT MIN(vils.start_date)   
           FROM vu_imp_list vils  
          WHERE vils.account_id = vil.account_id 
        );
```

Comment: Curious, which of the 3 queries did you want? (because all 3 are different.)

Answer (score 0):

If your table `vu_imp_list` has both `825808009` and `987323136` present for `account_id`, then this inner query:

```
(SELECT vils.account_id, MIN(vils.start_date)   
 FROM vu_imp_list vils  
 WHERE vil.account_id IN ('825808009','987323136')  
 group by vils.ob10_account_id)
```

will generate 2 rows, 2 columns each.

Trouble is, then you cannot do multi-column equality check in `WHERE`:

```
WHERE (vil.account_id, vil.start_date) =   
    (SELECT vils.account_id, MIN(vils.start_date) ... )
```